# Missing classpath entry carbon.home.folder\bin\org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap-4.2.0.jar

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I just tried to deploy my configurations to wso2 ESB inside eclipse and I got a following error message while deploying my CAR file to ESB. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Which version of WSO2 ESB are you using? Also, you should point the path to the bin folder of your wso2 esb.

Comment: wso2 esb 5.0.0. Where I have to point the bin folder path?

Comment: where it says CARBON_HOME - you can click the Browse... button and locate it. Actually, not the bin folder - the main folder (wso2esb-5.0.0). Also, it should be WSO2 Carbon 4.4 based server.

Comment: Thank you.It's working :) . Post above as a answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should point to the correct path of your WSO2 ESB instance (where the main folder is located). You can click the Browse... button next to the CARBON_HOME field and locate it.

Also, for WSO2 ESB 5.0.0, the correct version for the server should be WSO2 Carbon 4.4 based server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download WSO2 `ESB 5.0.0`. Go to [here](https://wso2.com/integration/previous-releases/). Select WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 and download server. Then browse this directory to Eclipse. If you can't go next, cancel the process, try again. It should work.